# How can I forward the audio output of my Ubuntu desktop to another (Debian) machine?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

(Full disclosure: I've asked a [question on the Pi side of this process](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29526/what-do-i-need-to-set-up-to-be-able-to-output-my-desktop-pcs-audio-through-my-p) over on the Pi StackExchange.)

I have a Raspberry Pi (with OSMC, so practically Debian) that I want to leave on permanently, and a desktop with Ubuntu 14.04. I want my speakers to be connected to the Pi so I can always use it, but when I'm using my desktop, I want to hear the sound from there.

Now, I figured I could save myself from having to plugging my speakers into each different system all the time by streaming the audio output from my desktop through the Raspberry Pi.

As far as I understand it, PulseAudio should allow me to do this. It's just that I'm not quite sure how to.

I currently have done the following.

In `paprefs` (on the desktop), is it enough to click "Enable Multicast/RTP sender", and to select the "RTP Multicast" output device in Sound prefences?

[image]

Then on the Pi (where I have no GUI), I installed PulseAudio, and edited `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to enable `pactl load-module module-rtp-recv`. After that, I tried to start PulseAudio through running `pulseaudio -D`.

Unfortunately, this did not cause audio played from my desktop to be emitted from the Pi. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While sending what are the sinks on your receiver (`pactl list short sinks`)? You may have to select the stream there.

Comment: @Takkat See here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10807715/ How can I select the stream?